# How do we write the pseudocode taking this part of code as an example?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtpostcode_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtpostcode.KeyUp
    
    If (Not Char.IsNumber(ChrW(e.KeyCode))) Then
        MsgBox("Please re-enter your postcode", vbExclamation)

        txtpostcode.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well pseudo code is really just a close to natural language interpretation of the process.  Normally done before coding as a design step.

Comment: This will be a very annoying user interface!  So if the user makes one tiny typo, they'll get a MsgBox, their entry will be deleted and they'll have to enter the whole thing in again.  This, as opposed to simply allowing them to use the backspace and/or arrow keys to fix their error.  Instead of handling the "error" in the `KeyUp` event, do some kind of validation in a Button `Click` handler, for example, and simply tell them where the error is so they can go fix it...

Comment: This is a very poorly written question. Nothing but code in the question and the question in the title is not how you write a good question. You write the question first, including a FULL and CLEAR explanation: this is what I'm trying to achieve, this is how I'm trying to achieve it and this is what happens when I try. The title is then a summary of the topic of the question, not the question itself. Apart from that, you need to show that you have made some effort on your own behalf to solve your problem and show us where you're stuck. Just saying "I need X, do it for me" is not OK at SO.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much for your comment. I will take it into consideration next time. Actually it was not such a big question.. Quite simple one asking for only the pseudocode of the vb syntax above.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you very much for your comment. I will try the button click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess psedo code is really a little open to personal style.  Me, I would go something like

```
If keypress is letter
  Show Messagebox
  Clear postcode
end if
```